# Insert text to a generated pdf document

Tags: java, pdf

I have a library which generates pdf document with images.
I want to be able to add text after each image. What is the syntax for that? How to insert text into pdf documents?

I have to use the library I have, not another one.

Comment: What library do you use? And what have you tried?

Comment: Its a custom library and it works well with pdfs with images. Now I want to know the syntax to define a page with text. I tried a few examples but they either make the pdf corrupted or just show no results.

Comment: So you want to extends this library? I approach could be to create that PDF with an other tool and analyze it to implement the functionality.

Comment: I have full control over the creation process I just want to know what is the pdf syntaxt for inserting text on a pdf page.

Comment: The PDF syntax is defined in the standard, have a look at [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). For text have a look at chapter 9 "Text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, mkl is correct, have a look at the specification for all of the details. PDF is an exact language, if you make mistakes they will routinely be punished severely once you open the PDF in viewers.

Secondly, when you think about putting text on the page, don't forget that besides the text operators to draw the text on the page, you'll also have to specify the font to use to draw this text. Which will include making sure there is a font resource included in the PDF file if your library doesn't automatically handle all of that for you.

If you want to cut corners (I shiver while writing this) and perhaps don't read the specification as thoroughly, try this.

1) Create a PDF file that looks more or less like what you want.

2) Use a tool such as pdfToolbox from callas (http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en:download) or Browser from Enfocus (http://www.enfocus.com/en/products/browser). Both of these tools allow you to investigate the low-level structure of a PDF file, including looking at the actual page description code. This will show you how fonts are embedded (if you have to do it yourself that could be very handy) and how text is rendered on the page (and how you set the font, size, color etc... to use).